# How to disable JSON escaping in H2 JSON field

Tags: mysql, hibernate, h2, compatibility

The following code

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  BBB;

CREATE TABLE BBB (id INT, data1 JSON, data2 TEXT);

insert into BBB (id, data1, data2) VALUES
(1, '{"a": 12}', '{"a": 12}');

SELECT *, CAST(data1 as TEXT) data3 FROM BBB;
```

causes different results in MySQL and H2.

In H2 it shows

[image]

while in MySQL it shows

[image]

I.e. `H2` adds unneded escaping. How to (is it possible to) make `H2` to behave the same as `MySQL` i.e. disable escaping of JSON fields?

Also workarounds with JPA/Hibernate are appreciated.

Comment: https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#json_type *To set a JSON value with java.lang.String in a PreparedStatement use a FORMAT JSON data format (INSERT INTO TEST(ID, DATA) VALUES (?, **? FORMAT JSON**)). Without the data format VARCHAR values are converted to a JSON string values.*

Comment: Why does MySQL behave differently?

Comment: "By design" :) Actually MySQL, like H2, can demonstrate the same issue if you provide the data incorrectly.

Comment: I have provided identical data identically. Can I configure identical behavior?

Comment: *Can I configure identical behavior?* I doubt. Different dialects provides different behavior - this is a norma.

Comment: This is an old known issue of Hibernate ORM: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14237

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the field type to text, and everything is working as expected for me:

```
CREATE TABLE BBB (id INT, data1 TEXT, data2 TEXT);
```